# Iterative MapReduce (Twister) running exception

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to run my MapReduce application.

This is the main class:

```
public class GPFunctionFitting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ....
        GPFunctionFitting client;
        try {
            client = new GPFunctionFitting();
            client.runMapReduce(partitionFile, numMapTasks); // line 44
            // ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And the method:

```
public ExpressionTree runMapReduce(String partitionFile, int numMapTasks) throws Exception {

        JobConf jobConf = new JobConf("gp-function-fitting-map-reduce" + uuidGen.generateRandomBasedUUID());
        jobConf.setMapperClass(GPMapTask.class);
        jobConf.setReducerClass(GPReduceTask.class);
        jobConf.setCombinerClass(GPCombiner.class);
        jobConf.setNumMapTasks(numMapTasks);
        jobConf.setNumReduceTasks(1);

        TwisterModel driver = new TwisterDriver(jobConf);
        driver.configureMaps(partitionFile); // line 74
        TwisterMonitor monitor = driver.runMapReduce();
        monitor.monitorTillCompletion();
        ExpressionTree solution = ((GPCombiner) driver.getCurrentCombiner()).getResult();

        driver.close();

        return solution;
    }
```

This is the log from eclipse console:

```
JobID:
gp-function-fitting-map-reduce9f25c1da-ab8b-446b-b453-d60f4165b3a9
TransmissionManager: There is a pending/ongoing transfer on
niotcp:///127.0.0.1:3045 for a total of 16384 bytes
TransmissionManager: All transfers have been completed
CommunicationsService: Closing Link =    niotcp://127.0.0.1:3045 null 0 
[main] INFO  cgl.imr.client.TwisterDriver  - MapReduce computation
termintated gracefully.

cgl.imr.base.TwisterException: Could not send all the map executor
requests. First error is Did not receive a response from the worker.14
[Thread-0] DEBUG cgl.imr.client.ShutdownHook  - Shutting down
completed.
    at cgl.imr.client.TwisterDriver.configureMaps(TwisterDriver.java:360)
    at cgl.imr.client.TwisterDriver.configureMaps(TwisterDriver.java:381)
    at map_reduce.GPFunctionFitting.runMapReduce(GPFunctionFitting.java:74)
    at map_reduce.GPFunctionFitting.main(GPFunctionFitting.java:44)
```

And, finally, the error from terminal where I've ran twister:

```
2588033 [Thread-4] ERROR cgl.imr.worker.DaemonWorker  - Could not
instantiate the Mapper. cgl.imr.base.TwisterException: Could not
instantiate the Mapper.     at
cgl.imr.worker.Mapper.<init   (Mapper.java:120)     at
cgl.imr.worker.DaemonWorker.handleMapperRequest(DaemonWorker.java:228)
    at cgl.imr.worker.DaemonWorker.onEvent(DaemonWorker.java:471)   
    at cgl.imr.pubsub.nb.NBPubSubService.onEvent(NBPubSubService.java:154)
    at cgl.narada.service.qos.impl.QosServiceImpl.routeToEventConsumer(QosServiceImpl.java:938)
    at cgl.narada.service.qos.impl.QosServiceImpl.manageEventRoutingToDestinations(QosServiceImpl.java:530)
    at cgl.narada.service.qos.impl.QosServiceImpl.processReceivedEvent(QosServiceImpl.java:424)
    at cgl.narada.service.qos.impl.CommunicationsService.processDataPackets(CommunicationsService.java:236)
    at cgl.narada.service.qos.impl.CommunicationsService.processData(CommunicationsService.java:214)
    at cgl.narada.service.qos.impl.CommunicationsService.handleData(CommunicationsService.java:142)
    at cgl.narada.transport.TransportHandlerImpl.dataReceived(TransportHandlerImpl.java:516)
    at cgl.narada.transport.niotcp.NIOTCPReceiverThread.processBuffer(NIOTCPReceiverThread.java:323)
    at cgl.narada.transport.niotcp.NIOTCPReceiverThread.processBuffer(NIOTCPReceiverThread.java:329)
    at cgl.narada.transport.niotcp.NIOTCPReceiverThread.processBuffer(NIOTCPReceiverThread.java:329)
    at cgl.narada.transport.niotcp.NIOTCPReceiverThread.processBuffer(NIOTCPReceiverThread.java:329)
    at cgl.narada.transport.niotcp.NIOTCPReceiverThread.processBuffer(NIOTCPReceiverThread.java:329)
    at cgl.narada.transport.niotcp.NIOTCPReceiverThread.processBuffer(NIOTCPReceiverThread.java:329)
    at cgl.narada.transport.niotcp.NIOTCPReceiverThread.processBuffer(NIOTCPReceiverThread.java:329)
    at cgl.narada.transport.niotcp.NIOTCPReceiverThread.processBuffer(NIOTCPReceiverThread.java:329)
    at cgl.narada.transport.niotcp.NIOTCPReceiverThread.processBuffer(NIOTCPReceiverThread.java:329)
    at cgl.narada.transport.niotcp.NIOTCPReceiverThread.processBuffer(NIOTCPReceiverThread.java:329)
    at cgl.narada.transport.niotcp.NIOTCPReceiverThread.processBuffer(NIOTCPReceiverThread.java:329)
    at cgl.narada.transport.niotcp.NIOTCPReceiverThread.processBuffer(NIOTCPReceiverThread.java:329)
    at cgl.narada.transport.niotcp.NIOTCPReceiverThread.readDataFromSocket(NIOTCPReceiverThread.java:247)
    at cgl.narada.transport.niotcp.NIOTCPReceiverThread.run(NIOTCPReceiverThread.java:196)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: map_reduce.GPMapTask   
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)   
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)    
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)    
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)    
at java.lang.ClassLoader.findSystemClass(ClassLoader.java:1004)     
at cgl.imr.util.CustomClassLoader.findClass(CustomClassLoader.java:102)
at cgl.imr.util.CustomClassLoader.loadClass(CustomClassLoader.java:129)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)  
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)  
at cgl.imr.worker.Mapper.<init   (Mapper.java:116)  ... 24 more
```

The class GPMapTask exists, implementing MapTask interface, and is in the same package with the main class.
Partition file is generated appropriately, and contains 12 lines, which equals to the number of map jobs that is requested.

Could somebody at least give me an idea where to look for a problem?
I have been trying to solve the "Class not found exception", but I am starting to believe that the problem lies in partition configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .class is either missing or exists in more than one location.
The compiler is then confused, since the class definition is ambiguous.
Make sure all classes are included, exactly once.
Check content of all jars included in the class path.

Delete bin folder, clean and build the project again.
With Twister, the .jar file of the application that is running has to be present in the apps/ directory. Export the newest version of application, whenever it changes (when run from IDE).

Comment: Why does it need to be in the apps directory? The JAR just needs to be accessible on all nodes at the same location, or preferably, on HDFS

Comment: Oh, Ok, I thought that location has to be apps/ directory.

Comment: Nope =) `hadoop jar hdfs:///path/to/file.jar` has mostly worked in my experience